# JS accessing an index of an array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, observable

I have some code that gets an array as an observable that sits in a separate component.

Now when I intialise the home component I get the array that I am trying to access, I get a value when I access the first element however when try and access any of the other elements I get undefined.

How to resolve this issue.

Here is my code.
Contact Component

```
public contactsChanged = new Subject();
  public updatedContact;
  key = 'contacts';
 mContacts = [
   {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    number: ''
   },
   {
    id: 1,
    name : '',
    number: ''
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    name : '',
    number: ''
   },
   {
    id: 3,
    name : '',
    number: ''
   }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.appData.currentContacts().subscribe((contacts: [string]) =>
    this.updatedContact = contacts);
    this.getContact();
  }
  dismiss() {
    this.modalController.dismiss({
      dismissed: true
    });
  }
  pickContact(contactId) {
    this.mContacts[contactId].name = "Mitchell";
    this.mContacts[contactId].number = (Math.random() * 0.5).toString();

    this.appData.changeContacts(this.mContacts);
    this.saveContacts();

    // this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact) => {

    //   this.mContacts[contactId].name = contact.name.givenName;
    //   this.mContacts[contactId].number = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value;
    //   this.appData.changeContacts(this.mContacts);
    //   this.saveContacts();
    //   console.log('Contacts saved: ');
    // });

  }
  saveContacts() {
    this.storage.set(this.key, JSON.stringify(this.mContacts));
  }
  getContact() {
    this.storage.get(this.key).then((val) => {
      console.log('Contact Name: ', val);
      if (val != null && val !== undefined) {
        this.mContacts = JSON.parse(val);
        this.appData.changeContacts(this.mContacts);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

The Service I am using for the Observables

```
 private contacts = new BehaviorSubject<[string]>(['']);

currentContacts(): Observable<[string]> {
     return this.contacts.asObservable();
  }

changeContacts(contacts) {
    this.contacts.next(contacts);
  }
```

and the home component that is trying to display the data

```
 this.appData.currentContacts().subscribe((contacts: [string]) => {
      this.mContacts = contacts;
      this.numberOne = this.mContacts[0].number;
      // this.numberTwo = this.mContacts[1].number;
      console.log("mContacts: " , this.mContacts);
      console.log("Contacts: " , contacts );
      console.log("mContacts num: " + this.mContacts[1].number);
    });
```

Now when I try and call
`this.mContacts[0].number` then that works but if I try `this.mContacts[1].number` then I get an error

`console.log(this.mContacts)` returns

```
0: Object { id: 0, name: "Mitchell", number: "0.27670880550635446" }
​
1: Object { id: 1, name: "Mitchell", number: "0.3120836066243317" }
​
2: Object { id: 2, name: "Mitchell", number: "0.20501487579574068" }
​
3: Object { id: 3, name: "Mitchell", number: "0.17382789003990085" }
```

Error Output when I try calling `this.mContact[1].number`

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.mContacts[1] is undefined"
```

Comment: "Now when I try and call `this.mContacts[0].number` then that works but if I try `this.mContacts[1].number` then I get an error" - What's the full error output?

Comment: @Tanner added the error output

Comment: Try logging `JSON.stringify(contacts)` in the line directly before accessing `this.mContacts[1]`.

Comment: @str I tried that, but still the same result.

Comment: Well, it wouldn’t be *exactly* the same result, since JSON looks different. What was the exact output?